# Rellenar el interior de una gráfica de tipo plot mediante matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo una gráfica que quiero rellenar de color. Hacerlo con un solo color es sencillo mediante `plt.fill(x,y,'color')`, como muestro en la imagen. El problema cuando quiero definir diferentes colores dentro de la misma. Es decir, yo quiero pasarle las coordenadas de que pinta punto a punto en su interior y así dentro dibujar el arco iris o lo que me de la gana.

```
x = [5,6,7,6,5,4,4,3,4]
y = [0,1,2,3,4,3.5,3,2,1.5]

plt.plot(x,y,'r')
plt.fill(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado cosas pero nada funciona, entonces la duda que me surge es ¿es `plt.fill()` la opción correcta?¿De que manera se puede hacer?

Algo que se me ocurrió es dividir la lista de coordenadas punto a punto e ir pasándola a `.fill()` pero eso me divide cómo si fueran diferentes partes.

```
x1 = [5,6,7,6,5]
x2 = [4,4,3,4]
y1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
y2 = [3.5,3,2,1.5]

plt.plot(x1,y1,x2,y2)
plt.fill(x1,y1,'b', x2,y2,'y')
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien podría ayudarme? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Intenté resolver tu pregunta con estas dos formas:

> Primera Forma

Siguiendo tu ejemplo podrías crear más coordenadas para llenar el espacio faltante:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [5,6,7,6,5]
x2 = [4,4,3,4]
x3 = [4, 5, 5, 4]
y1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
y2 = [3.5,3,2,1.5]
y3 = [1.5, 0, 4, 3.5]

# plt.plot(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)
plt.fill(x1,y1,'b', x2,y2,'y', x3,y3,'p')
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Segunda Forma

Leyendo otras preguntas he visto que se puede añadir varios polígonos en una gráfica con `PathCollection`, de la siguiente forma:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

patches = []

pol1 = matplotlib.patches.Polygon(np.array([[5, 0], [6, 1], [7, 2], [6, 3], [5, 4]]), color='#924d5f')
pol2 = matplotlib.patches.Polygon(np.array([[4, 3.5], [4, 3], [3, 2], [4, 1.5]]), color='#39873c')
pol3 = matplotlib.patches.Polygon(np.array([[4, 1.5], [5, 0], [5, 4], [4, 3.5]]), color='#2e7890')

patches.append(pol1)
patches.append(pol2)
patches.append(pol3)

p = PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True)

ax.add_collection(p)

plt.xlim([2, 7])
plt.ylim([0, 5])
plt.show()
```

Obteniendo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva.

Referencias:

[How to fill polygons with colors based on a variable in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141476/how-to-fill-polygons-with-colors-based-on-a-variable-in-matplotlib)

[How do I set color to Rectangle in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550477/how-do-i-set-color-to-rectangle-in-matplotlib)

[Set Polygon Colors Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44725201/set-polygon-colors-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

Aqui hay una prueba creando un abanico de triángulos con colores del arco iris.

```
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [5,6,7,6,5,4,4,3,4]
y = [0,1,2,3,4,3.5,3,2,1.5]
x.append(x[0])  # cierre el poligono
y.append(y[0])

n = 30
# divide cada lado del polígono en n trositos (con n=1 se guarde el polígono original)
x1 = [v+i/n*(w-v) for v, w in zip(x, x[1:]) for i in range(n)]+[x[0]]
y1 = [v+i/n*(w-v) for v, w in zip(y, y[1:]) for i in range(n)]+[y[0]]

poly_vertices = list(zip(x1, y1))
xm = sum(x)/len(x) # centro del polígono
ym = sum(y)/len(y)

# crea triangulos conectando cada 2 puntos con el centro
patches = [Polygon([poly_vertices[i], poly_vertices[i + 1], (xm, ym)],
                   closed=True,
                   color=plt.cm.gist_rainbow(i / len(poly_vertices)))
           for i in range(len(poly_vertices)-1)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True)
ax.add_collection(p)
ax.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

Resultado:
[image: el polígono con colores]

Comment: ¿Ha sido útil esta respuesta?